# adding "and" between authors in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I see several questions asking how to *remove* the and between authors, but my question is how can I add it? After much pain I was able to obtain the citing (author, year) but this resulted in loosing the "and" between authors (in norwegian "and" is "og") how can this be fixed? =)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@Book{test1,
  author    = {Einar M. Skaalvik, Sidsel Skaalvik},
  title     = {Skolen som læringsarena: \emph{Selvoppfatning , motivasjon og læring}},
  publisher = {Universitetsforlaget},
  location  = {Oslo},
  year      = {2002},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                             % Vise norske tegn.
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}                            % Tilpasning til norsk.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                          % For å kunne skrive norske tegn.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\andname{and}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{, }
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\author{Øistein Søvik, Silje, Magnus , Maja}
\title{PPU4000 \\ Examen Paedagogicum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 

\tableofcontents

\section{Innledning}

\section{Teori}

\section{Metode og beskrivelse}


\subsection*{Lærerens rolle i klasserommet}

 Hello hello somewhat of a test \autocite{test1}
 Do not mind me, plow plow plow your boat,     

\section{Drøftning}

\section{Avslutning}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your database entry is wrong: there you _always_ need `and` between names. (It has to be `and`: BibTeX expects this to be in English.)

Comment: {Skaalvik, Einar M. and Skaalvik, Sidsel}, worked like a charm, thank you. Biblatex is still a bit like dark magic.

Comment: Ooops ... I would've known that. Didn't look at the BibTeX entry at all when we were chatting.

Comment: @JosephWright Make that an answer, please (or cast the first closing vote).

Comment: @lockstep I'd think other users could make this mistake and find this post helpful (with a formal answer to it). Writing `author = {Author and Buthor and Cuthor and Duthor}` isn't exactly intuitive.